# OO strategy to match a set of tokens to an appropriate method / constructor

Tags: java, parsing, tokenize

This question isn't specifically about performing tokenization with regular expressions, but more so about how an appropriate type of object (or appropriate constructor of an object) can be matched to handle the tokens output from a tokenizer.

To explain a bit more, my objective is to parse a text file containing lines of tokens into appropriate objects that describe the data. My parser is in fact already complete, but at present is a mess of `switch`...`case` statements and the focus of my question is how I can refactor this using a nice OO approach.

First, here's an example to illustrate what I'm doing overall. Imagine a text file that contains many entries like the following two:

```
cat    50    100    "abc"
dog    40    "foo"  "bar"   90
```

When parsing those two particular lines of the file, I need to create instances of classes `Cat` and `Dog` respectively. In reality there are quite a large number of different object types being described, and sometimes different variations of numbers of arguments, with defaults often being assumed if the values aren't there to explicity state them (which means it's usually appropriate to use the builder pattern when creating the objects, or some classes have several constructors).

The initial tokenization of each line is being done using a `Tokenizer` class I created that uses groups of regular expressions that match each type of possible token (integer, string, and a few other special token types relevant to this application) along with `Pattern` and `Matcher`. The end result from this tokenizer class is that, for each line it parses, it provides back a list of `Token` objects, where each `Token` has a `.type` property (specifying integer, string, etc.) along with primitive value properties.

For each line parsed, I have to:

- `switch`...`case` on the object type (first token);
- `switch` on the number of arguments and choose an appropriate constructor
  for that number of arguments;
- Check that each token type is appropriate for the types of arguments needed to construct the object;
- Log an error if the quantity or combination of argument types aren't appropriate for the type of object being called for.

The parser I have at the moment has a lot of `switch`/`case` or `if`/`else` all over the place to handle this and although it works, with a fairly large number of object types it's getting a bit unwieldy.

Can someone suggest an alternative, cleaner and more 'OO' way of pattern matching a list of tokens to an appropriate method call?

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar, where I have decoupled my parser from code emitter, which I consider anything else but the parsing itself. What I did, is introduce an interface which the parser uses to invoke methods on whenever it believes it has found a statement or a similar program element. In your case these may well be individual lines you have shown in the example in your question. So whenever you have a line parsed you invoke a method on the interface, an implementation of which will take care of the rest. That way you isolate the program generation from parsing, and both can do well on their own (well, at least the parser, as the program generation will implement an interface the parser will use). Some code to illustrate my line of thinking:

```
interface CodeGenerator
{
     void onParseCat(int a, int b, String c); ///As per your line starting with "cat..."
     void onParseDog(int a, String b, String c, int d); /// In same manner
}

class Parser
{
    final CodeGenerator cg;

    Parser(CodeGenerator cg)
    {
        this.cg = cg;
    }

    void parseCat() /// When you already know that the sequence of tokens matches a "cat" line
    {
         /// ...

         cg.onParseCat(/* variable values you have obtained during parsing/tokenizing */);
    }
}
```

This gives you several advantages, one of which being that you do not need a complicated `switch` logic as you have determined type of statement/expression/element already and invoke the correct method. You can even use something like `onParse` in `CodeGenerator` interface, relying on Java method overriding if you want to always use same method. Remember also that you can query methods at runtime with Java, which can aid you further in removing `switch` logic.

```
getClass().getMethod("onParse", Integer.class, Integer.class, String.class).invoke(this, catStmt, a, b, c);
```

Just make note that the above uses `Integer` class instead of the primitive type `int`, and that your methods must override based on parameter type and count - if you have two distinct statements using same parameter sequence, the above may fail because there will be at least two methods with the same signature. This is of course a limitation of method overriding in Java (and many other languages).

In any case, you have several methods to achieve what you want. The key to avoid `switch` is to implement some form of virtual method call, rely on built-in virtual method call facility, or invoke particular methods for particular program element types using static binding.

Of course, you **will** need at least one `switch` statement where you determine which method to actually call based on what string your line starts with. It's either that or introducing a `Map<String,Method>` which gives you a runtime switch facility, where the map will map a string to a proper method you can call `invoke` (part of Java) on. I prefer to keep `switch` where there is not substantial amount of cases, and reserve Java `Map`s for more complicated run-time scenarios.

But since you talk about "fairly large amount of object types", may I suggest you introduce a runtime map and use the `Map` class indeed. It depends on how complicated your language is, and whether the string that starts your line is a keyword, or a string in a far larger set.

Comment: Class<Integer> is a type, not a value.  You need Integer.class

Comment: Many thanks @amn; really appreciate the time you've put into this. It gives me some inspiration, though at the moment I don't fully grasp if this can solve the problem of having lots of messy if/switch statements to ensure that the tokens received match the argument requirements of each object's constructor. Example: for one particular object, I need to check that there are 5 tokens, 4 of which are integer and the final is a string; otherwise, log an error. It may be best if I post some example code. In the meantime there's good inspiration here, particularly use of reflection and maps.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in the question; you want a Strategy, basically a Map where the key would be, e.g., "cat" and the value an instance of:

```
final class CatCreator implements Creator {
    final Argument<Integer> length = intArgument("length");
    final Argument<Integer> width = intArgument("width");
    final Argument<String> name = stringArgument("length");

    public List<Argument<?>> arguments() {
        return asList(length, width, name);
    }

    public Cat create(Map<Argument<?>, String> arguments) {
        return new Cat(length.get(arguments), width.get(arguments), name.get(arguments));
    }
}
```

Supporting code that you would reuse between your various object types:

```
abstract class Argument<T> {
    abstract T get(Map<Argument<?>, String> arguments);
    private Argument() {
    }

    static Argument<Integer> intArgument(String name) {
        return new Argument<Integer>() {
            Integer get(Map<Argument<?>, String> arguments) {
                return Integer.parseInt(arguments.get(this));
            }
        });
    }

    static Argument<String> stringArgument(String name) {
        return new Argument<String>() {
            String get(Map<Argument<?>, String> arguments) {
                return arguments.get(this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm sure someone will post a version that needs less code but uses reflection.  Choose either but do bear in mind the extra possibilities for programming mistakes making it past compilation with reflection.

Comment: Thanks @Ricky Clarkson; your time to provide this answer is much appreciated. Similar in my response to amn, I'm not entirely sure if/how this will help solve the main thing I don't 'like' about my present code: that there is a large mess of if/switch to perform validation that the correct quantity and types of tokens have been parsed for a given object type. I may just have to devise some kind of pattern matching scheme to tidy that up. I like the suggestion about maps. I'm going to look over this code again tomorrow (when more awake!) to ensure I properly follow it.

Comment: Well, given a Map<String, Creator> creators, after reading the token cat into a string you would call creators.get(string) to get a Creator, then call creator.arguments() to get a List<Argument<?>>, keep reading more tokens, adding them to a Map<Argument<?>, String> values, and when you have one String for each Argument<?> call creator.get(values) to get the resultant object out.  It might take some tweaks to exactly match what you want but I hope it's a good start.